# PF_BRIDGE(NF_BR_PRE_ROUTING) hook not getting invoked

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, netfilter

1. There is Kernel module which registers a function as PF_BRIDGE hook to net filter using nf_register_hook()
2. Hook function is not getting called from kernel.
3. Is there any kernel specific change needed?
   What's possible reason for such a behaviour? I do not see any error also.

Comment: Do you have any interfaces in a bridge? PF_BRIDGE hooks are only called for bridged packets.

Comment: @JoelC sorry, I am not familiar with usage of PF_BRIDGE. I desperately need thorough example. Do you mean I need to configure bridge in Linux and also need to attach one of the interface to that?

Comment: @JoelC My purpose is to get all the packets those arrive on interface eth0, to my kernel module. Wouldn't it be better to use netdev_rx_handler_register instead of complex PF_BRIDGE (Including bridge). Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this thread? Is this what you are looking for?

[Netfilter hook on router not getting called for bridged interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40557375/2755904)

In this thread, I have suggested to use the following nf_hook_ops.

```
.pf     = PF_BRIDGE,
.hooknum    = NF_BR_PRE_ROUTING,
.priority   = NF_BR_PRI_FIRST,
```